# what if my device doesn't support work profiles?

Tags: android, android-security

I want to create an android enterprise app that manages which apps to show to an owner device.

I tried the BasicManagedProfile sample but I got "This device doesn't support work profiles" on my device.

Is it possible to do something else to get the same behavior?

Maybe I can get the same with a launcher that gets locked and show the apps that I want, is that possible without work profiles? Any other suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the sample do you following?

Comment: BasicManagedProfile , under "File -> Import sample..." In Android Studio

Comment: FYI : https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7029561?hl=en

Comment: and also refer this : https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/7083920?hl=en